# What is difference between INNER join and OUTER join

Tags: sql, join

Difference between inner and outer join. i am using two table and want to fetch data from both table so which type join we should use owning of that we can solve our problem

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Inner join - An inner join using either of the equivalent queries gives the intersection of the two tables, i.e. the two rows they have in common.
Left outer join -
A left outer join will give all rows in A, plus any common rows in B.
Full outer join - 
A full outer join will give you the union of A and B, i.e. All the rows in A and all the rows in B. If something in A doesn't have a corresponding datum in B, then the B portion is null, and vice versa.
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 112):

This is the best and simplest way to understand joins:

[image]

**Credits go to the writer of this article [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)**

Answer (score 18):

INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables

LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows from the right table

RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched rows from the left table

FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

Comment: I like the simple way that you have explained it.

Answer (score 1):

Inner join matches tables on keys, but outer join matches keys just for one side.
For example when you use left outer join the query brings the whole left side table and matches the right side to the left table primary key and where there is not matched places null.